# I need to sell an almost-complete MMORPG project. How can I do that?

Tags: mmo, marketing, sales

I need your help. We have to sell MMORPG at an advanced stage. The game has a unique engine, written on the need for the game, graphics, sound, map editor, web site etc.

As it happens in the play mmorpg we can develop the characters, monsters. We can fight with other characters or to establish cooperation in solving the challenges. We can fight using own monsters, or throwing their own cards with spells.

Unfortunately we have no idea how to promote the game. Ended fund and I think the whole team surrendered. How can I find a buyer? Where can I find him? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the game finished? Also this is not a site for classified ads.

Comment: The game is not quite finished. You can play, but there is only one world / island. I'm sorry if I put the question the wrong place. I need help. But if this is not the place for such things, please delete the post.

Comment: I edited the post to make it clearer that this is a question and not an advertisement (and removed the advertisey bit, sorry).

Comment: Why not take the game to a crowd-funding platform like [kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/)? If the people like it, they will fund your game so that you can finish it.

Comment: Did not even know that there is a possibility. I would like to team took hope again :) To take advantage of the kickstarter need to be a producer from the USA?

Comment: @Tomasz I never started a project myself. The website states that you have to be an US citizen, but I have already backed projects from UK and other places in Europe. Not sure how they did it... maybe directly get in touch with kickstarter?

Comment: @Tomasz You should fill in your profile, there is no rule saying you can't promote your game through it. And if you keep engaging with the community here, that will help promote you and your game.

Comment: Finding a buyer for a completed software project or game is a rather huge topic, and it also has more to do with business than actual game development. I don't think this question is appropriate here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 15):

I see two questions here: How can I secure funding for finishing my game? and How do I handle promotion of my game?

### Getting Started

I believe this is the perfect situation to apply the [Minecraft Model](http://www.wired.co.uk/magazine/archive/2012/07/features/changing-the-game?page=all) to. Setup a site for your game. Get registration working. Start selling subscriptions cheap, $1-3 a month, or even sell lifetime memberships for $10-25.

As Bummzack says, get it on kickstater.

Engage in the MMO community, engage in the game dev community, engage in the hobby homebrew community. Get on social media. Allow the few early adopters and people who love your videos and screenshots to fund the early needs like the server. Iterate forever.

### Next Steps

It doesn't matter how bad it looks to start with, you only need to get a few people to buy it to start. Just keep making it better and fun. Always fun.

Expand the options for players, always tying back to the core game play. Make everything support that one unique aspect of your game. If your game is a world based on living cards, make everything the player does either need cards they already have or give them new cards. If the point of your game is monster collection, make everything need attributes of monsters to work.

If you want to add item crafting to the game, make it require iron cards/monsters and fire cards/monsters to be able to craft those items. Focus on the economy of your game. In Minecraft, that economy is blocks that were mined. Everything in the game needs those mined blocks.

If you keep giving the players new ways, weekly or at worst monthly, to make use of the items they already have, then you will keep them coming back for years. And they will tell their friends and you will keep getting new sales or subs and therefore new players.

### Downside

The major problem with this is your game has to be really fun and engaging to be successful with this model. It works because you build a community around something that a few really interested people love. Minecraft initially appealed only to a certain type of lego-centric player, however they kept adding features to the game that appealed to other types of gamers and eventually broke out and grew exponentially. For me, it was the addition of mine-cart roller-coasters that got me to buy it.

If your game can't grab people by the throat and not let go. If it isn't fun and totally engaging for hours on hours, this model won't work.

Comment: Your Minecraft-model link seems to be awol...